# GroupBy .Key printing literal Index

Tags: c#, list, group-by

I am sorting a list of `strings` by the order of another list of `strings`

```
List<string> lstCategories = new List<string>() { "string1", "string2", "string3"};

var groups = lstActivity.OrderBy(x => x.codeAC.Text).ThenBy(x => x.text).GroupBy(x => lstCategories.IndexOf(x.codeAC.Text));

foreach(var group in groups)
{
    var slg = new SelectListGroup() { Name = group.Key.ToString() }; //problem is here

    foreach(codeAC activity in group)
    {
        SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem() { Text = activity.text, Value = activity.ID.ToString(), Group = slg };
        lstAssignments.Add(item);
    }
}
```

The output of this is:

```
- 2          // I need this to be the text & not the index position
    * text1
    * text2
- 1
    * text3
    * text4
- 3
    * text5
    * text6
// so on and so on
```

The *group* is the literal **index position** of the list `lstCategories`.. How do I get it to *Select* the text and use that as the group and not the index position?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you group by index position then?

Comment: @IvanStoev because the order of the groups by default needs to be changed to a specific order, which is the `lstCategories`.. so I need the default list's group's ordered in the same order as `lstCategories`

Comment: Well, then just **order** them after grouping: `.GroupBy(x => x.codeAC.Text).OrderBy(g => lstCategories.IndexOf(g.Key))`

Comment: @IvanStoev thank you. that worked. Idk why I didn't think to order after the grouping... but thank you again. you can post and i will give you the credit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing grouping with ordering. After grouping you can order groups as well as group elements as you wish. In your sample not only the group key is not what you want, but also the result is not ordered (2, 1, 3).

Here is the query that does what you want:

```
var groups = lstActivity.OrderBy(x => x.codeAC.Text).ThenBy(x => x.text)
    .GroupBy(x => x.codeAC.Text)
    .OrderBy(g => lstCategories.IndexOf(g.Key));
```

and the of course use simply

```
var slg = new SelectListGroup() { Name = group.Key };
```